# Dictionary form vs Teiru form for habits

Tags: て-form

Some people say the ている form can be used to talk about regular habits. I'm not sure, but sometimes the dictionary form seems to be used in the same way. Is there any difference between them in that context? Is there a way to know which to use? The sentence that made me think about it I found it in a grammar book. The sentence is:

> マヌエル君のお母さんはとてもきれいな絵を描きます。

Would it be possible to say the same thing with 描いています? Is it the same thing? If not, how can I know?